# Accessing URL Parameters in deployed webapp

Tags: google-apps-script

I can't seem to access URL parameters in my simple webapp. From the documentation it looks very simple:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var foo = (e.parameters.test);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Test: " + foo);    
}
```

But foo keeps coming back as "undefined" when I run the webapp, either using the "my latest code" developer link, or a deployed version.

I've also noticed that when the page loads the URL Parameters I tack on at the end disappear.

The URL looks like:

https://script.googleusercontent.com/a/macros/mysite.com/echo?user_content_key=superlongstring&lib=otherstring&test=helloworld

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should tack on the parameter before the script URL redirects.

So it should look like -

https://script.google.com/macros/s/longstring/exec?test=helloworld

[image]

The redirected URL is really only for the output and its not re-usable and it wont trigger any new processing.